# How to gracefully stop XMLHttpRequest on Bootstrap modal close in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, bootstrap-modal

I am currently working on a project where I use Bootstrap modals to display dynamic content fetched via XMLHttpRequest (XHR). The modal is opened successfully, and the XHR request is initiated. However, I am facing an issue when trying to gracefully stop the XHR request when the Bootstrap modal is closed.

```
        if (response.value === "1") {


        } else if (response.value === "2") {


        } else if (response.value === "3") {
            var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal'));

            modal._element.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function() {

            });

            modal._element.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function() {

                stopRequest(); // Stop the XMLHttpRequest when the modal is closed
            });

            modal.show();
            var qId = '86868';
            var xhr; // Declare xhr globally

            function sendRequest() {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Assign xhr globally
                var url = "fetch_status.php?qId=" + qId;

                xhr.open("GET", url, true);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xhr.status == 200) {
                            var responseData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            if (responseData.status === "success") {

                                window.location.href = "redirect_page.php";

                            } else {
                                setTimeout(sendRequest, 5000);
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.error("Error:", xhr.status);
                        }
                    }
                };

                // Send the request
                xhr.send();
            }

            function stopRequest() {
                if (xhr) {
                    // Check if the request is still in progress before aborting
                    if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        xhr.abort();
                        console.log("XHR aborted");
                    }
                }
            }
            sendRequest();
        } else {
            // Handle other cases or show an error message

        }
```

I have a modal that opens successfully, and I initiate an XHR request to fetch data. I am using the Bootstrap framework for the modal. I have implemented an event listener for the modal's 'hidden.bs.modal' event to call a function (stopRequest) that should abort the XHR if it's still in progress.

Specific Issues:
The modal is displaying as expected.
XHR requests are being sent successfully.
The 'hidden.bs.modal' event is triggering the stopRequest function.
However, the XHR doesn't seem to be reliably aborting, leading to potential issues.

Request for Assistance:
I am seeking guidance on how to properly handle the abortion of an ongoing XMLHttpRequest when a Bootstrap modal is closed. Any insights, suggestions, or corrections to my current approach would be greatly appreciated.